# New to tkinter tuple has no attribute

Tags: python, attributes, tkinter

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

# the constructor syntax is:
# OptionMenu(master, variable, *values)

speed = [
    "fast",
    "medium",
    "slow"
]

master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set(speed[0]) # default value

w =(OptionMenu, (master, variable) + tuple(speed))
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "S:/KS4/Year 10/Computing/Python/tkinter.py", line 18, in <module>
    w.pack()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pack'
```

Comment: Note that, when editing, I have assumed that lines 3 and 4 of your code should be comments, as they aren't valid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `w` is a tuple, indeed you can see as much if you `print(w)`:

```
(<class 'tkinter.OptionMenu'>, (<tkinter.Tk object at 0x02F97F30>, <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x02FAE970>, 'fast', 'medium', 'slow'))
```

This is a two-tuple where:

- The first element `w[0]` is the `OptionMenu` class object; and
- The second element `w[1]` is itself a tuple, containing five elements:

  - The `master` `Tk` instance;
  - The `variable` `StringVar` instance; and
  - The three `str` instances from `speed`.

I doubt this is anything like what you were hoping for. Looking at the assignment:

```
w =(OptionMenu, (master, variable) + tuple(speed))
```

You have a comma after the class name, which makes this a tuple. Contrast a working assignment, where the parentheses open immediately after the class name, and close after the arguments:

```
variable = StringVar(master)
```

Presumably, you wanted:

```
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *speed)
```

Note that this is the syntax that is **actually mentioned in your code**.